# Piecewise regression with a quadratic polynomial and a straight line joining smoothly at a break point

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, piecewise

I want to fit a piecewise linear regression with one break point `xt`, such that for `x < xt` we have a quadratic polynomial and for `x >= xt` we have a straight line. Two pieces should join smoothly, with continuity up to 1st derivative at `xt`. Here's picture of what it may look like:

[image: piecewise regression]

I have parametrize my piecewise regression function as:

[image: regression function]

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `xt` are parameters to be estimated.

I want to compare this model with a quadratic polynomial regression over the whole range in terms of adjusted R-squared.

Here is my data:

```
y <- c(1, 0.59, 0.15, 0.078, 0.02, 0.0047, 0.0019, 1, 0.56, 0.13, 
0.025, 0.0051, 0.0016, 0.00091, 1, 0.61, 0.12, 0.026, 0.0067, 
0.00085, 4e-04)

x <- c(0, 5.53, 12.92, 16.61, 20.3, 23.07, 24.92, 0, 5.53, 12.92, 
16.61, 20.3, 23.07, 24.92, 0, 5.53, 12.92, 16.61, 20.3, 23.07, 
24.92)
```

[image: scatter plot]

My attempt goes as follows, for a known `xt`:

```
z <- pmax(0, x - xt)
x1 <- pmin(x, xt)
fit <- lm(y ~  x1 + I(x1 ^ 2) + z - 1)
```

**But the straight line does not appear to be tangent to the quadratic polynomial at `xt`.** Where am I doing wrong?

---

Similar questions:

- [Piecewise regression with a straight line and a horizontal line joining at a break point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30060278/4891738)
- [Fitting a V-shape curve to my data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/248206/117783) (on Cross Validated)

Comment: And the question is? If you are not sure how to go about this, maybe this would be of use: [R for Ecologists: Putting Together a Piecewise Regression](https://climateecology.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/).

Comment: This is a question for Cross Validated, as it refers to a Statistical model and not programming.  That being said, you're going to want to use a dummy variable to nest the two models in one equation.  For example. y = I + ax + bx^2*(I-1), were I takes a value of 1 when x>=xt and 0 otherwise

Comment: Are you after continuity and continuity of the first derivative? Is finding the breakpoint your main problem or is defining the predictors your main problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this section I will be demonstrating a reproducible example. Please make sure you have sourced functions defined in the other answer.

```
## we first generate a true model
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(100)  ## sample points on [0, 1]
beta <- c(0.1, -0.2, 2)  ## true coefficients
X <- getX(x, 0.6)  ## model matrix with true break point at 0.6
y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(100, 0, 0.08)  ## observations with Gaussian noise
plot(x, y)
```

[image: scatter plot]

Now, assume we don't know `c`, and we would like to search on a evenly spaced grid:

```
c.grid <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.05)
fit <- choose.c(x, y, c.grid)
fit$c
```

[image: choose c]

`RSS` has chosen 0.55. This is slightly different from the true value `0.6`, but from the plot we see that `RSS` curve does not vary much between `[0.5, 0.6]` so I am happy with this.

The resulting model `fit` contains rich information:

```
#List of 12
# $ coefficients : num [1:3] 0.114 -0.246 2.366
# $ residuals    : num [1:100] 0.03279 -0.01515 0.21188 -0.06542 0.00763 ...
# $ fitted.values: num [1:100] 0.0292 0.3757 0.2329 0.1087 0.0263 ...
# $ R            : num [1:3, 1:3] -10 0.1 0.1 0.292 2.688 ...
# $ sig2         : num 0.00507
# $ coef.table   : num [1:3, 1:4] 0.1143 -0.2456 2.3661 0.0096 0.0454 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "beta0" "beta1" "beta2"
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
# $ aic          : num -240
# $ bic          : num -243
# $ c            : num 0.55
# $ RSS          : num 0.492
# $ r.squared    : num 0.913
# $ adj.r.squared: num 0.911
```

We can extract the summary table for coefficients:

```
fit$coef.table
#        Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#beta0  0.1143132 0.009602697 11.904286 1.120059e-20
#beta1 -0.2455986 0.045409356 -5.408546 4.568506e-07
#beta2  2.3661097 0.169308226 13.975161 5.730682e-25
```

Finally, we want to see some prediction plot.

```
x.new <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
p <- pred(fit, x.new)

head(p)
#           fit     se.fit       lwr       upr
#[1,] 0.9651406 0.02903484 0.9075145 1.0227668
#[2,] 0.8286400 0.02263111 0.7837235 0.8735564
#[3,] 0.7039698 0.01739193 0.6694516 0.7384880
#[4,] 0.5911302 0.01350837 0.5643199 0.6179406
#[5,] 0.4901212 0.01117924 0.4679335 0.5123089
#[6,] 0.4009427 0.01034868 0.3804034 0.4214819
```

We can make a plot:

```
plot(x, y, cex = 0.5)
matlines(x.new, p[,-2], col = c(1,2,2), lty = c(1,2,2), lwd = 2)
```

[image: confidence band]

Answer (score 6):

This is an excellent exercise (maybe hard) to digest the theory and implementation of linear models. My answer will contain two parts:

- Part 1 (this one) introduces the parametrization I use and how this piecewise regression reduces to an ordinary least square problem. R functions including model estimation, break point selection and prediction are provided.
- Part 2 (the other one) demonstrates a toy, reproducible example on how to use those functions I have defined.

**I have to use a different parametrization because the one you gave in your question is wrong!** Your parametrization only ensures continuity of function value, but not the first derivative! That is why your fitted line is not tangent to the fitted quadratic polynomial at `xt`.

---

[image: Parametrization]

```
## generate design matrix
getX <- function (x, c) {
  x <- x - c
  cbind("beta0" = 1, "beta1" = x, "beta2" = pmin(x, 0) ^ 2)
  }
```

[image: Using AIC to select c]

[image: Using RSS to select c]

[image: grid search to find c]

Function `est` below wraps up `.lm.fit` (for maximum efficiency) for estimation and inference of a model, at a given `c`:

```
## `x`, `y` give data points; `c` is known break point
est <- function (x, y, c) {
  ## model matrix
  X <- getX(x, c)
  p <- dim(X)[2L]
  ## solve least squares with QR factorization
  fit <- .lm.fit(X, y)
  ## compute Pearson estimate of `sigma ^ 2`
  r <- c(fit$residuals)
  n <- length(r)
  RSS <- c(crossprod(r))
  sig2 <- RSS / (n - p)
  ## coefficients summary table
  beta <- fit$coefficients
  R <- "dimnames<-"(fit$qr[1:p, ], NULL)
  Rinv <- backsolve(R, diag(p))
  se <- sqrt(rowSums(Rinv ^ 2) * sig2)
  tstat <- beta / se
  pval <- 2 * pt(abs(tstat), n - p, lower.tail = FALSE)
  tab <- matrix(c(beta, se, tstat, pval), nrow = p, ncol = 4L,
                dimnames = list(dimnames(X)[[2L]], 
                c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "t value", "Pr(>|t|)")))
  ## 2 * negative log-likelihood
  nega2logLik <- n * log(2 * pi * sig2) + (n - p)
  ## AIC / BIC
  aic <- nega2logLik + 2 * (p + 1)
  bic <- nega2logLik + log(n) * (p + 1)
  ## multiple R-squared and adjusted R-squared
  TSS <- c(crossprod(y - sum(y) / n))
  r.squared <- 1 - RSS / TSS
  adj.r.squared <- 1 - sig2 * (n - 1) / TSS
  ## return
  list(coefficients = beta, residuals = r, fitted.values = c(X %*% beta),
       R = R, sig2 = sig2, coef.table = tab, aic = aic, bic = bic, c = c,
       RSS = RSS, r.squared = r.squared, adj.r.squared = adj.r.squared)
  }
```

As you can see, it also returns various summary as if `summary.lm` has been called. Now let's write another wrapper function `choose.c`. It sketch `RSS` against `c.grid` and return the best model with selected `c`.

```
choose.c <- function (x, y, c.grid) {
  if (is.unsorted(c.grid)) stop("'c.grid' in not increasing")
  ## model list
  lst <- lapply(c.grid, est, x = x, y = y)
  ## RSS trace
  RSS <- sapply(lst, "[[", "RSS")
  ## verbose
  plot(c.grid, RSS, type = "b", pch = 19)
  ## find `c` / the model minimizing `RSS`
  lst[[which.min(RSS)]]
  }
```

So far so good. To complete the story, we also want a `predict` routine.

```
pred <- function (model, x.new) {
  ## prediction matrix
  X <- getX(x.new, model$c)
  p <- dim(X)[2L]
  ## predicted mean
  fit <- X %*% model$coefficients
  ## prediction standard error
  Qt <- forwardsolve(t(model$R), t(X))
  se <- sqrt(colSums(Qt ^ 2) * model$sig2)
  ## 95%-confidence interval
  alpha <- qt(0.025, length(model$residuals) - p)
  lwr <- fit + alpha * se
  upr <- fit - alpha * se
  ## return
  matrix(c(fit, se, lwr, upr), ncol = 4L,
         dimnames = list(NULL, c("fit", "se", "lwr", "upr")))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%E6%9D%8E%E5%93%B2%E6%BA%90) is a genius but I would like to suggest another solution, using the Heaviside ([unit step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) function, H(x) = 1 if x>0; H = 0 if x ≤ 0

```
H <- function(x) as.numeric(x>0)
```

Then, the function to fit is f(x,c) = b0 + b1 (x-c) + b2 (x-c)^2 H(c-x), and can be used with nls:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ b0+b1*(x-c)+b2*(x-c)^2*H(c-x), 
            start = list(b0=0,b1=0,b2=1,c=0.5))
```

Testing it with the [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%E6%9D%8E%E5%93%B2%E6%BA%90)'s toy example, gives

```
summary(fit)$parameters

     Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
b0  0.1199124 0.03177064  3.774315 2.777969e-04
b1 -0.2578121 0.07856856 -3.281365 1.440945e-03
b2  2.4316379 0.40105205  6.063148 2.624975e-08
c   0.5400831 0.05287111 10.215089 5.136550e-17
```