# Fitting different parts of data to different models in R

Tags: r

I've had a pet personal project trying to dig through my Dad's old thesis from 1972 and to reproduce a computational solution that he derived. His project was looking at the kinetics of a transition state for alumina ceramics. After collecting the data, he derived the following model for the kinetic curve of the transition (see attached image from his thesis).

[image: Modified Johnson's equation]

In case the picture doesn't come through, the data form a s shaped curve. To the left of the inflection point t* the data fit the equation

```
y = A * exp(K*t)
```

To the right of the inflection point, the data fit the equation

```
y = 1 - B * exp(-J * t^n)
```

He wrote up a fortran program using Fortran 68 that does dynamic modeling and least squares fitting for this. I am trying to "update" his code to see if I can do it more efficiently in R. So two questions:

1. What is the best way to just plot his model? i.e. how to plot two equations in this manner. I feel like I could do it brute force with base R, but I'm not sure that it will transition between the two equations smoothly.
2. In his model, the coefficients A, K, B, J and n as well as the inflection point t* are unknown and are optimized by least squares. He does his modeling in fortran by brute force. Is there a glm or similar solution in R for solving this elegantly?

Here is a sample of the data that he generated:

```
y <- c(20,30,40,50,55,60,65,70,80,90,100,110,120,150)
t <- c(0.05,0.11,0.185,0.31,0.375,0.445,0.52,0.63,0.8,0.92,0.97,0.98,0.99,0.999)
```

Comment: This looks like it would answer your question - [piecewise function fitting with nls() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874214/piecewise-function-fitting-with-nls-in-r)

Comment: There is a great GAM package by Hastie et al. in R. Here is a minimal example. Cool project btw! https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/GAM_regression_splines_simulated_data.R

Comment: Nice project. Couldn't you fit this model with a single logistic curve?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I will try out some.of those packages and see how well they do for this problem.