# R: Error in is.nloptr(ret) : inequality constraints in x0 returns NA

Tags: r, optimization, runtime-error, nonlinear-optimization

I was trying to solve a nonlinear optimization problem using `nloptr` package in R, [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/index.html).

```
library('nloptr')

#parameters 
N_h <- c(39552, 38347, 43969, 36942, 41760)

s_h1 <- c(4.6, 3.4, 3.3, 2.8, 3.7)

s_h2 <- c(11.7, 9.8, 7.0, 6.5, 9.8)

s_h3 <- c(332, 357, 246, 173, 279)

Cost <- c(3,4,5,6,7)

C_cap <- c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)

c<- Cost+C_cap
N <- sum(N_h)
d_h <- c(N_h/N)
d1 <-(d_h)^2*s_h1
d2 <-(d_h)^2*s_h2
d3 <-(d_h)^2*s_h3



#Objective
f0<-function(x, d1, d2, d3, c, Gamma){
 return(x[1])
}


#Constraints
g0<- function(x, d1, d2, d3, c, Gamma){
   return(c((c[1]*x[2]+c[2]*x[3]+c[3]*x[4]+c[4]*x[5]+c[5]*x[6]+x[7]*Gamma+sum(x[8:12])-x[1]),

       (-x[7]-x[8]+c[1]*x[2]),
       (-x[7]-x[9]+c[2]*x[3]),
       (-x[7]-x[10]+c[3]*x[4]),
       (-x[7]-x[11]+c[4]*x[5]),
       (-x[7]-x[12]+c[5]*x[6]),
       (d1[1]/x[2]+d1[2]/x[3]+d1[3]/x[4]+d1[4]/x[5]+d1[5]/x[6]-0.5037),
       (d2[1]/x[2]+d2[2]/x[3]+d2[3]/x[4]+d2[4]/x[5]+d2[5]/x[6]-0.50868),
       (d3[1]/x[2]+d3[2]/x[3]+d3[3]/x[4]+d3[4]/x[5]+d3[5]/x[6]-0.55),
       (x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]-1081)
   ))
    }

  #Initialization and algo
x0<-c(100, 10,10,10,10,10,  2,  2,2,2,2)



Rob2 <- nloptr(x0=x0,
                eval_f = f0,
                lb=c(-Inf, 2,2,2,2,2,  0,  0,0,0,0),
                ub=c(Inf, 1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,  Inf,  Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf),
                eval_g_ineq=g0,
                opts=list("algorithm"="NLOPT_GN_MLSL",
                          maxeval=100000,
                          "xtol_rel"=1.0e-8,
                          "print_level" = 2),
                d1=d1, d2=d2,d3=d3, c=c, Gamma=Gamma)
```

On running this algorithm the Error is as follows:

```
   Error in is.nloptr(ret) : inequality constraints in x0 returns NA
```

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciable.!!

#Edit

The original problem is like follows

```
Min x[1]
subject to
-x[7]-x[8]+c[1]*x[2]<=0
-x[7]-x[9]+c[2]*x[3]<=0
..
..
x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]-1081<=0
```

Comment: I have also tried with "algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA" but still it is not working.

Comment: Could you please include constraints and objective function in  inequality(equality)  format for aid in comprehension e.g. `a*x + b*y <= c`

Comment: Actually, the constraints should be in the form of g(x)<= 0; as i am using an R interface to NLopt.

Comment: That was just an example can you list out the constraints, in words not in code, so readers can understand what is the optimization problem you are trying to solve. A good example could be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358238/finding-a-curve-to-match-data)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is that you include constant values with the initial x0, you need to put it separately as d1<-2
                                 d2<-2

Comment: Is this a wild guess or an educated guess? If it's the latter, it's better not to use the phrase "I guess". People will think that this is a comment disguised as an answer because you can't comment yet. (Happens all the time).